# Class member inheritance in nodejs + expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, inheritance

I don't quite understand how class inheritance and context is working in nodejs + expressjs.

I have 3 files :

**api.js**

```
class API {
  constructor () {
    this._id = Math.random()
    console.log("Instantiated id:" + this._id)
  }

  list (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Instantiated id:" + this._id)
  }
}
module.exports = API
```

**user.js**

```
const API = require('./api.js')

class UserAPI extends API {

  constructor () {
    super()
  }
}
module.exports = UserAPI
```

**route.js**

```
var UserAPI = require('./user.js')
var user = new UserAPI()
router.get('/', user.list);
```

What I would like to see is the ID when starting then the same ID each time I do a GET request.
But when I do a GET request I have : `ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`

How can I have access to member in the Base class when deriving it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Classes are syntactic sugar for JS's prototypal inheritance. I your case ```this``` no longer comes from the class when you pass the function to ```router.get```. Convert your ```list``` to an arrow function and it will work

Comment: Or ```router.get('/', user.list.bind(this));```

Comment: When I change to `router.get('/', user.list.bind(this));` I get `Instantiated id:undefined`

Comment: ```id:undefined```? You don't even have an ```id```. Check for typo's

Comment: It's just the line of text in the console.log: `console.log("Instantiated id:" + this._id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not class inheritance, but simply the way you use the list method. You are passing it directly to `router.get`, that won't work, because you are only passing a reference to the function, which then doesn't know the context of the instance of `UserAPI`.

You can fix this by passing an anonymous function to `router.get` that then executes `user.list`, like this:

**route.js**

```
var UserAPI = require('./user.js')
var user = new UserAPI()
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => user.list(req, res, next));
```

Answer (score 0):

Making API inheritance with express is impossible. Check[ZinkyJS](https://zinkyjs.github.io/), it makes exactly what you want to do.